# FuelPHP simple class Not Found Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, fuelphp

This is my first deployment of FuelPHP, though I am a long time user of CodeIgniter.

I am getting the following error when I load the page:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
Class 'Model\Model_UPS' not found
```

/classes/controller/ups.php

```
<?php
use \Model\Model_UPS;
class Controller_UPS extends Controller {
    public function action_index() {
        $view = View::forge('json');
        $view->title = Model_UPS::get_load();
        return $view;
    }
}
?>
```

/classes/model/model_ups.php or ups.php

```
<?php
namespace Model;
class Model_UPS extends \Model {
    public static function get_load() {
        return "This is the load!";
    }
}
?>
```

/views/json.php

```
<?=$title;?>
```

The error page highlights the `$view->title = Model_UPS::get_load();` line of ups.php. I have tried just about every configuration of use, namespace, model filename, and model class name that I can think of. I can't seem to find a super simple MVC example to use as a guide. I've tried to duplicate the FuelPHP Docs as best as I can, but have failed. Can anyone find anything wrong with this?

Comment: I don't know about codeigniter, but using namespaces and pseudo-underscore-namespaced-class-names seems weird to me: `\Model\Model_UPS`; may it should read: `\Model\UPS`…

Comment: CodeIgniter required these prefixes because it doesn't namespaces, and it also doesn't support folder cascading (all classes are in the same folder) which is another reason for long and underscored class names. This is not needed in FuelPHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Rename file: **model/model_ups.php** to **model/ups.php**
- Rename class: **Model_UPS** to **UPS**
- Change: **use \Model\Model_UPS;** to **use \Model\UPS;**
- Change: **Model_UPS::get_load();** to **UPS::get_load();**

Comment: This worked! Can you describe why the different areas need to be named so specifically? Maybe I'm asking how they appropriately interact. There was a note in the FuelPHP docs about how you can use Model_ as a prefix to your models. If I wanted to do that, do I just make it model_ups.php, Model_UPS, use \Model\Model_UPS, and Model_UPS::get_load()? I could have sworn I tried that, maybe I didn't.

Comment: FuelPHP uses a cascading file system, similar to Kohana (and up to a point CodeIgniter as well). This system is compatible with pre-namespace times, and uses the underscore to create a folder hierarchy, so A_B_C will become a/b/c.php in the filesystem. Now, I would not use underscores at all, only namespaces at all, like vmartins suggests.